# how do i delete a file from azure blob based on file path in Django

Tags: django, azure, django-rest-framework, azure-blob-storage

MODELS.PY

```
class FilesHistory(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,  null=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/%y/%m/%d/',null=False,blank=False)
    sentGroupId = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)

   def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
       self.file.storage.delete(self.file.path)
       super().delete()
```

this delete function is working for removing files from the media folder based on the file path.

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue in detail?